# $F(z,w) = F(e^{i \theta} z,e^{i \theta} w)$ then $F$ is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I need a help with the following statement:

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ be a domain containing $(0,0)$ and let $F:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic such that
$$F(z,w) = F(e^{i \theta} z,e^{i \theta} w),$$
for any $(z,w) \in D$, and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Here we assume that $(e^{i \theta} z,e^{i \theta} w) \in D$, for any $(z,w) \in D$, and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

Show that $F$ must be a constant.

---

### As Martin mentioned below, I have to add the fact that $D$ contains the origin.

In one dimension the conclusion follows by the fact if a holomorphic function is constant on a path then it is constant on the whole domain. But I don't know how to verify the case in 2 dimension.

Comment: What about $F(z, w)=z/w$ on $D= (\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \})^2$?

Comment: @Martin Yes. How about if I impose that $(0,0) \in D$.

Comment: Just write the double power series near $(0,0)$ and identify coefficients from the identity

Comment: @Conrad Thanks, it's such a very straight direction.